# Boosting elasticsearch based on boolean field value

Tags: json, elasticsearch, boolean

Hi I'm new to elasticsearch, I'm to trying boost based on a boolean filed value.

I have a list of article, I want to get all the article where the word "louvre" is found inside the title.

And boost the active articles before the inactive ones. I still want to be able to see both active and inactive articles. But on the top of the list the active ones.

This is what I got so far:

```
 {
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "louvre",
      "fields": [  "title", "isActive(true)^3", "isActive(false)^2" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"title": "louvre"}}
      ],
      "should": [
        {"term": {"isActive": {"value": true}}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```